# Multiple stored procedures in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have this and it works fine:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from tblA; SELECT * from tblB",cs);
```

I want this:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("spA; spB",cs);
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

It says I can only use one stored procedure at a time. How can I use this two queries with two stored procedures?

Comment: You can only call a single SP with `SqlDataAdapter`. But you can create an SP that calls several other SPs

Comment: Also, you can perform **two** `SELECT`s in a single SP

Comment: @Basuro I have a single Dataset and DataAdapter for this. Should I use two different DataSets and DataAdapters if I go with the Store procedure route? Is the right way to do this.

Comment: @Basuro I need to get the data from each of this queries. How can it be retrieved for each query if they are in the same SP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spC AS
    @param_for_A int,          -- Parameter for SP 'spA'
    @param_for_B nvarchar(50)  -- Parameter for SP 'spB'
BEGIN
    EXEC spA @sqA = @param_for_A;
    EXEC spB @sqB = @param_for_B;
END
```

**C#**

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("spC", cs);
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param_for_A", 123));
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param_for_B", "demo"));
DataSet myDS = new DataSet();
da.Fill(myDS);
```

The `ds.Tables` collection then contains all returned tables, in order:

- ds.Tables[0] - Result of first 'SP in SP'
- ds.Tables[1] - Result of second 'SP in SP'

Comment: is it da.Tables or ds.Tables? da.Tables doesnt exist

Comment: I have a parameter sqA in spA and parameter sqB in spB. I am getting this Error: Procedure or function 'spA' expects parameter '@sqA', which was not supplied. Procedure or function 'spB' expects parameter '@sqB', which was not supplied

Comment: Then put both parameters into the params list of spC and give them to the respective SPs

Comment: How do I do this? I am new with stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of would be to create a third stored proc that calls both the stored procedures you want to call.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is that you can pass multiple store procedure as text . 
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

put comma between them .

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing to use an SqlDataReader - it can cope with multiple result sets by using the NextResult method.

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL mandates that stored procedures are executed as `EXEC MyProc;` for all cases except when the batch has just one statement -- in which case, the use of "EXEC" is optional. To execute two stored procedures, in your example, you just have to add these to the statement string:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("EXEC spA; EXEC spB",cs);
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text; // optional (it's default)
```

[more information on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189915.aspx)

Comment: I get this
Error: Could not find stored procedure 'EXEC spA; EXEC spB'.

Comment: That's just a message that these stored procedures don't exist, @Apollo. You have to create your own stored procedures and change "spA" and "spB" by their proper names. Do you need help creating SPs?

Comment: I created the stored procedures. They work fine if is just one but not when is two.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Apollo, I mismatched the command type. The response was corrected. It should work as expected now.